How to interpret the area of effect rules
The rules as written for spell area of effects seem strange to me.

An area of effect has a point of origin, a location from which the effect’s energy erupts. The rules for each shape specify how to position its point of origin. If all straight lines extending from the point of origin to a location in the area of effect are blocked, that location isn’t included in the area of effect. To block a line, an obstruction must provide Total Cover. See also “Cover.”


If the creator of an area of effect places it at an unseen point and an obstruction—such as a wall—is between the creator and that point, the point of origin comes into being on the near side of the obstruction.

Just for context the rules on Total Cover

Total, Can’t be targeted directly, Provided by: An object that covers the whole target

Whilst the rules as written seem clear and cut, a spell acts like a candle emitting light in a particular shape. everything being lit is affected by the spell everything else is not.
However this has some odd implications, some examples

Antilife shell (Emanation) could be blocked by a large enough wooden panel, allowing you to bypass the spell
Darkness (Sphere) is worded as "Fills a sphere", making it confusing if this uses the normal mechanics, which would give rise to the same bypass as described earlier.
Flame Strike, "Each creature in a 10-foot-radius, 40-foot-high Cylinder centred on a point within range" , this seems to use yet another AOE mechanic.
Purify Food and Drink, would not work on an opaque sealed container
Other spells suffer from the same oddities

Whilst the RAW seems clear, I feel that how people are currently using the spells does not align with how the rules are written.
Is this how the rules where intended or is this an unfortunate oversight or am I missing something?

I think this answer, Casting a spell in a smaller space than the spell itself?, under the 2014 rules, is still valid for the question asked.

Purify Food and Drink would not work on a transparent sealed container, either. Cover is a physical barrier, not necessarily a visual one. (Same as in 2014)

You are correct; a creature or object behind total cover cannot be directly targeted and is outside of a spell's area of effect. The examples you provide are all examples of total cover blocking a spell's effect.

I feel that how people are currently using the spells does not align with how the rules are written.

I agree there is some truth to this, based on my own experience. But of course, others' mileage will vary.
It is worth noting that this is the case with the 2014 5e rules as well. In fact, I don't see any meaningful changes in how spells and total cover interact from 5e-2014 to 5e-2024. I think the 2024 rules were reworded in attempt at greater clarity. Do they succeed? You decide.
2024 rules:

Cover
Targets
Area of Effect

2014 rules, for comparison:

Total Cover
A Clear Path to the Target

